# How do I get an individual hashtag from the twitter API? (using json in javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, twitter

So I'm using the npm 'twit' with node js to access the twitter API. What I want is the be able to fetch each of the hashtags used by a particular user in their last few tweets.

I am able to view the hashtags as part of an array using:

```
var Twit = require('twit');

var T = new Twit({
  //contains keys
});

var params = { 
  screen_name: '...', 
  count: 10,
}

T.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, gotData); 

function gotData(err, data, response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tweet = data[i].text;
    console.log(data[i].entities.hashtags);
  }
}
```

From this I get an output of an array of the tweets from each tweet, e.g.

```
[{text:'hashtag',indices:[10, 8]}]
```

I've tried to use:

```
data[i].entities.hashtags[0].text
```

in a variety of variations but it never seems to work.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the json object or a fiddle? Looks roughly right - assuming there is a first element in the hashtags array for every entity element.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline this has an example of the json object on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I amended the sample snippet on the twitter dev page to include hashtag objects like you noted in the question. You seem to be on the right track, so without a working example of your issue I'm not sure what's wrong. Perhaps you are trying to access the 0th index on every set of hashtags when some are empty?

Here's how I logged the tags' text using nested for loops:

```
for (var i = 0; i < example_data.length; i++) {
  console.log('Hashtags array: ', example_data[i].entities.hashtags); // hashtags is an Array < {text:<string>,indices:Array<number>} >
  var current_hashtags = example_data[i].entities.hashtags;
  for (var j = 0; j < current_hashtags.length; j++) {
    console.log('Hashtag: ', current_hashtags[j].text);
  }
}
```

You could also use map (or 3rd party libraries) to extract the text, such as:

```
var tags = example_data.map(tweet => tweet.entities.hashtags.map(hashtag => hashtag.text));

var tags = example_data.map((tweet) => {
  return tweet.entities.hashtags.map((hashtag) => {
    return hashtag.text;
  });
});
```

Below is a full working fiddle.

```js
var example_data = [{
  "coordinates": null,
  "favorited": false,
  "truncated": false,
  "created_at": "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012",
  "id_str": "240859602684612608",
  "entities": {
    "urls": [{
      "expanded_url": "/blog/twitter-certified-products",
      "url": "s://t/MjJ8xAnT",
      "indices": [
        52,
        73
      ],
      "display_url": "dev.twitter.com/blog/twitter-c\u2026"
    }],
    "hashtags": [{
      text: 'hashtag',
      indices: [10, 8]
    }],
    "user_mentions": [

    ]
  },
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "contributors": null,
  "text": "Introducing the Twitter Certified Products Program: https://t/MjJ8xAnT",
  "retweet_count": 121,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "id": 240859602684612608,
  "geo": null,
  "retweeted": false,
  "possibly_sensitive": false,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "place": null,
  "user": {
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "name": "Twitter API",
    "profile_image_url": "://a0/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
    "created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",
    "location": "San Francisco, CA",
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
    "is_translator": false,
    "id_str": "6253282",
    "entities": {
      "url": {
        "urls": [{
          "expanded_url": null,
          "url": "",
          "indices": [
            0,
            22
          ]
        }]
      },
      "description": {
        "urls": [

        ]
      }
    },
    "default_profile": true,
    "contributors_enabled": true,
    "favourites_count": 24,
    "url": "",
    "profile_image_url_https": "s://si0/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
    "utc_offset": -28800,
    "id": 6253282,
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "listed_count": 10775,
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "lang": "en",
    "followers_count": 1212864,
    "protected": false,
    "notifications": null,
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "s://si0/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
    "verified": true,
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
    "description": "The Real Twitter API. I tweet about API changes, service issues and happily answer questions about Twitter and our API. Don't get an answer? It's on my website.",
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "profile_background_image_url": "://a0/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "statuses_count": 3333,
    "friends_count": 31,
    "following": null,
    "show_all_inline_media": false,
    "screen_name": "twitterapi"
  },
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "source": "YoruFukurou",
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null
}, {
  "coordinates": null,
  "favorited": false,
  "truncated": false,
  "created_at": "Sat Aug 25 17:26:51 +0000 2012",
  "id_str": "239413543487819778",
  "entities": {
    "urls": [{
      "expanded_url": "/issues/485",
      "url": "s://t/p5bOzH0k",
      "indices": [
        97,
        118
      ],
      "display_url": "dev.twitter.com/issues/485"
    }],
    "hashtags": [

    ],
    "user_mentions": [

    ]
  },
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "contributors": null,
  "text": "We are working to resolve issues with application management & logging in to the dev portal: https://t/p5bOzH0k ^TS",
  "retweet_count": 105,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "id": 239413543487819778,
  "geo": null,
  "retweeted": false,
  "possibly_sensitive": false,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "place": null,
  "user": {
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "name": "Twitter API",
    "profile_image_url": "://a0/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
    "created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",
    "location": "San Francisco, CA",
    "follow_request_sent": false,
    "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
    "is_translator": false,
    "id_str": "6253282",
    "entities": {
      "url": {
        "urls": [{
          "expanded_url": null,
          "url": "",
          "indices": [
            0,
            22
          ]
        }]
      },
      "description": {
        "urls": [

        ]
      }
    },
    "default_profile": true,
    "contributors_enabled": true,
    "favourites_count": 24,
    "url": "",
    "profile_image_url_https": "s://si0/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
    "utc_offset": -28800,
    "id": 6253282,
    "profile_use_background_image": true,
    "listed_count": 10775,
    "profile_text_color": "333333",
    "lang": "en",
    "followers_count": 1212864,
    "protected": false,
    "notifications": null,
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "s://si0/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
    "verified": true,
    "geo_enabled": true,
    "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
    "description": "The Real Twitter API. I tweet about API changes, service issues and happily answer questions about Twitter and our API. Don't get an answer? It's on my website.",
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "profile_background_image_url": "://a0/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
    "statuses_count": 3333,
    "friends_count": 31,
    "following": null,
    "show_all_inline_media": false,
    "screen_name": "twitterapi"
  },
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "source": "YoruFukurou",
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null
}];



example_data.map(tweet => tweet.entities.hashtags.map(hashtag => hashtag.text));

for (var i = 0; i < example_data.length; i++) {
  console.log('Hashtags array: ', example_data[i].entities.hashtags); // hashtags is an Array < {text:<string>,indices:Array<number>} >
  var current_hashtags = example_data[i].entities.hashtags;
  for (var j = 0; j < current_hashtags.length; j++) {
    console.log('Hashtag: ', current_hashtags[j].text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks a lot, still not sure where I was going wrong before but this is working perfectly now so thanks a bunch :)